# Format date/time, in milliseconds, to local string in Android

Tags: android, time

I have a date/time that is specified in milliseconds which is retrieved by:

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

I would like to format this to a string that represents the date and time in whatever the local format is on the device. For example:

```
US:      12/15/2013 10:30 pm
Germany: 15.12.2013 22:30
```

I shouldn't have to specify the formatting such as:

```
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy h:mm a");
```

Is there an API that handles local formatting?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();    
Date today = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat.SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(SimpleDateFormat.LONG, SimpleDateFormat.LONG, locale).format(today));
```

where you need to check `locale` and pass its value accordingly.

Comment: My time is in milliseconds. It may not be "today". It could be any time. Is the value of Date the same thing in milliseconds?

Comment: Yes, its the same thing as `new Date()` also uses milliseconds.

Comment: This does not include time. It only provides a date.

Comment: This does not include time. It only provides a date. Furthermore, it does not format the date according to the user's system setting. In Android, the user can select various formats. Your example forces it to format according to the LONG format.

Comment: @AndroidDev If you want it to provide you default values then just use `SimpleDateFormat.DEFAULT` instead of `LONG` and yes it includes time as well. Have you really tried running this code ?

Comment: Clearly you did not test this code yourself. In Android, if you go to Settings and bring up the dialog that shows the user settings for Date format and set it to something, your code above will not give you the results of that date format. That's why you got down voted.

Comment: You've only asked the question w.r.t to default locale of location, you didn't mentioned that there would be change of format depending upon user settings. And yes I've tested the code prior to updating it here however I didn't check it on android sdk as I believe what you've asked corresponds to `Java` more than what you are assuming without mentioning in your post.

Comment: I wrote "local format" which implies the OS format set by the user. As for Android, the tag indicates that.

Answer (score 0):

See this code

```
    String myformat = android.provider.Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(),     android.provider.Settings.System.DATE_FORMAT);
    DateFormat dateFormat;
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(myformat)) {
      dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getMediumDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
    } else {
      dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    }
```

so dateformat will match with your device date

Answer (score 0):

check [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html). Specially

```
public static final DateFormat getDateInstance(int style,
                                               Locale aLocale)
```

Here is an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/FourdifferentdateformatsforfourcountriesUSUKGERMANYFRANCE.htm). See if it can help.

Answer (score -2):

As an option you can store a format string in string resources to make it available via

```
getResources().getString(R.string.format)
```

Then just put strings you need to locale folders, for example:

```
res/values-en/strings.xml
res/values-fr/strings.xml
```